# Converting advanced stored procedure from T-SQL to PL-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I want to convert manually below stored procedure from T-SQL(MS SQL Server 2008) to P-SQL(Oracle DB 11g). I recently try to convert this procedure using SQL Developer and SwisSQL Tool, but without success. This stored procedure contains one parameter @sptotest for the searching one word. Here is the code:

T-SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name @sptotest sysname AS

DECLARE @d            datetime,
       @tookms       int,
       @cnt          int,
       @single_email varchar(80),
       @word         varchar(50)

DECLARE @testwords TABLE
       (no   int         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        word varchar(80) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE #temp(person_id  int          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                  first_name nvarchar(50) NULL,
                  last_name  nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
                  birth_date datetime     NULL,
                  email      varchar(80)  NOT NULL)



SELECT TOP 1 @single_email = email
FROM   persons
WHERE  person_id BETWEEN 321106 AND 325000 AND  email LIKE '%.com'
ORDER  BY person_id


INSERT @testwords(no, word)
  SELECT 1, 'joy'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, @single_email

PRINT '------------------ Testing ' + ' ' + quotename(@sptotest) + ' ----'

DECLARE cur CURSOR STATIC LOCAL FOR
  SELECT word FROM @testwords ORDER BY no
OPEN cur

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
  FETCH cur INTO @word
  IF @@fetch_status <> 0
     BREAK

  TRUNCATE TABLE #temp

  CHECKPOINT
  DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS


  SELECT @d = getdate()
  INSERT #temp
     EXEC @sptotest @word
  SELECT @tookms = datediff(ms, @d, getdate())
  SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM #temp
  PRINT ltrim(str(@tookms)) + ' ms, ' +
        ltrim(str(@cnt)) + ' rows. Word = "' + @word + '".'


  TRUNCATE TABLE #temp
  SELECT @d = getdate()
  INSERT #temp
     EXEC @sptotest @word
  SELECT @tookms = datediff(ms, @d, getdate())
  SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM #temp
  PRINT ltrim(str(@tookms)) + ' ms, ' +
        ltrim(str(@cnt)) + ' rows. Word = "' + @word + '". Data in cache.'

END

DEALLOCATE cur
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to spend a few words about what the stored proc should do and what's wrong with your translation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Firstly translations are normally off-topic but as you've posted what you're trying to translate it to well done and thank you! This makes your question a lot better and more answerable. However, we also need to know _what's_ wrong with your translation. Why isn't it working? Did you get any errors and what were they? Does it not provide the same result? What result were you expecting and what is the procedure trying to do?

Comment: Most of the time you do not need all those workarounds using temp tables in Oracle as Oracle does not lock rows when you select them. If you can with just a single query that will be much better in Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a table inside a procedure directly. You have to use `execute immediate` to create a global temporary table. You would need to use `declare`

A cursor declaration must be in declaration part that mean above the `begin` statement.

I tried to correct the possible errors and I didn not test it, because I don't have an  instance. Please do the modifications as needed based on my example.

Small Example for Execute Immediate #

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create table t23 as  select ''1'' aa from dual'; 
  execute immediate 'update t23 set aa =''2'' where aa=''1''';
  COMMIT ;
end;

And your Proc Follows

create or replace procedure test_sp 
(
sptotest in varchar2 default null
)
 as
d date;
tookms number;
cnt number;
single_mail varchar2(80);
word varchar2(50);

cursor cur is select word from testwords order by no;

begin
execute immediate ('create global temporary table testwords
(
no     int          not null,
word   varchar2(80) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(no)
)');

execute immediate ('create global temporary table temp
(
person_id   int           not null,
first_name  nvarchar2(50) null,
last_name   nvarchar2(50) not null,
birth_date  date          null,
email       varchar2(80)  not null,
PRIMARY KEY(person_id)
)');

select Colm_name into Variable_name
from persons
where person_id between 311106 and 32500 and email like '%.com'
order by person_id;

insert into testwords
(
no, 
word
)
select 1, 'joy' from Table_name1
union all
select 4, single_email from Table_name2;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(  '------------------ Testing '  || ' '  || CAST(sptotest AS  VARCHAR2)  || ' ----');  

open cur; 
 -- Cursor Processing
Close Cur;
end test_sp;
/
```

Comment: Hi a_house_with_no_name, I used your stored procedure converted in pl/sql but when i run the procedure there are errors like: Error(12,15): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Hi @a_house_with_no_name, I used your stored procedure converted in pl/sql but when i run the procedure there are errors like: **Error(12,15): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, Error(12,32): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, Error(37,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, Error(42,22): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, Error(46,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IvanB d't run as it is, i used dummy columns and tables in the proc, changed to your tables and try to correct those minor errors.

Comment: Hi @Dileep, I'm so sorry for the above comment because I'm new to oracle pl-sql and I did not run the procedure correctly, your procedure is WORKING. Also can you please show me how to convert the above lines of the procedure:                                                           WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
  FETCH cur INTO word
  IF @@fetch_status <> 0
     BREAK

  TRUNCATE TABLE #temp

  CHECKPOINT
  DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS


  SELECT d = getdate()
  INSERT #temp
     EXEC sptotest word
  SELECT tookms = datediff(ms, d, getdate())
  SELECT cnt = COUNT(*) FROM #temp

Comment: For your question everything is to be related in Cursor. please read about Cursor attributes, so that u 'll get to know how to use. open Cursor If cur%notfound then exit..

Comment: Hi @Dileep, thanks for the instructions.